# variable won't change in PHP class

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, methods

The method -- initially called in index.php -- redirects to another page. The problem here is that variable `$logged_in` isn't getting assigned a new value... which means that when the variable is used in the other page, it is read as `false`.

NOTE: The assignment of session 'id' and session 'type' is correct.

```
class Session {    
    public $logged_in = false;
    public function login($data) {
        if ($data) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
            $_SESSION['type'] = $data['type'];
            $this->logged_in = true;            
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a class and therefore is lost (its properties are lost) at the end of the first scripts execution and then recreated in the second in its initial state.

Classes do not live across executions of the same script or any other script.

If you wish to maintain the objects state, you will have to save the state to a file or maybe the real SESSION so you can re-hydrate the data when the second script starts

```
session_start();

class Session {    

    public function login($data) {
        if ($data) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
            $_SESSION['type'] = $data['type'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;            
        }
    }

    // getter function
    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        // just in case check
        if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) ) {
            return $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Called like this

```
$s = new Session();
if ( ! $s->is_logged_in() ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

To keep it away from the SESSION completely you could

```
class Session {
    public $id;
    public $type;
    public $logged_in;


    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( file_exists('my_session.txt')) {
            $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('my_session.txt'));
            foreach($obj as $prop => $val) {
                $this->{$prop} = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        file_put_contents('my_session.txt', json_encode($this));
    }

    public function login($data) {
        if ($data) {
            $this->id           = $data['id'];
            $this->type         = $data['type'];
            $this->logged_in    = true;
        }
    }
}


$obj = new Session();
$obj->login(array('id'=>99, 'type'=>'TEST'));

print_r($obj);

$obj = null;

echo 'object nulled' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($obj);
echo ' NOTHING should be printed' . PHP_EOL;

echo 'object rehydrated' . PHP_EOL;
$obj = new Session();
print_r($obj);
```

Comment: nice solution and probably im gonna do it that way....but is there anyway i can keep it away from the session?

Comment: Well you could `serialize()` the class, that would capture all the properties and write that to a file in the destruct method and reload it in the constructor. Or use `json_encode()` and `json_decode`

Comment: thanks guys, but i got an idea and solved it....liked your solutions though and learned from them

Comment: There is my attempt at the final solution

Answer (score 0):

create another method check_login() to re-assign the values in the new page and call it within __construct()

```
function __construct(){
    $this->check_login();
}
public function check_login(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['type']){
        $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
        $this->logged_in = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought you wanted to stay away from session

Comment: I know i used the session here, but i didn't put 'ture' in the session....i think i didn't make my self clear enough...sorry for that....thanks for your solution though....I learned a lot from it